# How i can delete a portion of my text in many record of mysql db?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, replace

I want to know how I can delete all the strings that start with "MyString" and end with "AnotherString"? this because inside ( the string ) there is a number that changes every time.
I have about 30 strings to delete for each record ( all different but that start and end always the same) and 1000 records. Is there a query that does this?

I see this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = REPLACE(post_content, "mystring", "another_string")
```

but this work if the string is the same. ( the string that i want delete inside hava a number that change every time.

exist a query that performs this :

```
delete or replace with ""  all string ( inside my code ) that start with "xxxxx" and finish with "yyyy" ?
```

this is two string ( example ) that i must delete:  ( top: and left: is always different! )

```
<span style="border-radius: 2px; text-indent: 20px; width: auto; padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px; text-align: center; font: bold 11px/20px 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ffffff; background: #bd081c no-repeat scroll 3px 50% / 14px 14px; position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 8675309; display: none; cursor: pointer; top: 844px; left: 275px;">Salva</span>

<span style="border-radius: 2px; text-indent: 20px; width: auto; padding: 0px 4px 0px 0px; text-align: center; font: bold 11px/20px 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,sans-serif; color: #ffffff; background: #bd081c no-repeat scroll 3px 50% / 14px 14px; position: absolute; opacity: 1; z-index: 8675309; display: none; cursor: pointer; top: 766px; left: 350px;">Salva</span>
```

is possible when i find inside my code the string that start with `<span style` 
 and finish with `</span>`  delete it ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Is this for MySQL 8.0+ ? Because then one could use a [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) for that?

Comment: If you know what the strings are, then why can't you write a query to remove them?  Put another way, how do you plan to delete something which you have no knowledge of?

Comment: I have several strings (rows) to be deleted. These strings are inside other code that I have to keep.

Strings always change but they always start and end in the same way

Comment: The example data and expected output isn't clear.. Can you elaborate this beter?

Comment: I modified the post I hope now we understand better

Comment: How many `<span>` tags appear in each string?

Comment: <span style="border-radius: ...........</span>   two tags open and closed

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(post_content, LEN('string') + 1), 'string')
WHERE post_content LIKE 'string%';
```

Comment: I modified the post I hope now we understand better

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
UPDATE wp_posts
SET post_content = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(post_content,
                                    1,
                                    INSTR(post_content, '<span') - 1),
                          SUBSTRING(post_content,
                                    INSTR(post_content, '</span>') + 7))
WHERE post_content LIKE '%<span%</span>%';
```

### Demo

The logic here is to splice out a presumed single `<span>` tag as you described in your question and comments.

Comment: the string always changes...I modified the post to make me understand better

Comment: I modified the post I hope now we understand better

Comment: @FabrizioSavino I updated my answer per what my latest understanding of your question is.

Answer (score 0):

This untested `update` updates the items with start with `'start'` and end with `'end'` and sets `post_content` to have the value between them.

```
update wp_posts
set post_content = SUBSTRING(post_content, LEN('start') + 1, LEN('post_content') - LEN('end'))
where post_content LIKE 'start%' and post_content like '%end';
```

Comment: I modified the post I hope now we understand better